# How to delete lines in a file based on the indices in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file which is of this format:

```
1  2  [2, 3, 5]

2  5  [3, 4]

5  6  [4, 5]

4  9  [1, 6]
```

I need to write a script that deletes the lines having the first column equals to the indices in the list of each line. But, if a line has been processed, then it is safe.

For example, when it goes to the first line, it reads the list first, the indices inside is 2, 3 and 5. So it would delete line with first column 2, 3 and 5. So the second and third line are deleted. When it comes to the fourth line, it has indices 1 and 6. However, this time, line 1 has been processed so it would not delete the first line but the line starts with 6.

`

```
for x, line in enumerate(f):
     a = line.split('\t')
     a[2] = ast.literal_eval(a[2])
     index = [a[2]]
     for element in index:
         data = pd.read_csv(path[x:-1, :], sep='\t', header=None, engine='python', index_col=0)
         data.drop(element, inplace=True)
```

`

Comment: What specific part of this project are you having trouble with? Can you show what you have so far and describe exactly how it's failing?

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, highlighting the exact lines where you're having problems, detailing the errors. Make sure that the code you post can be executed by anyone, to reproduce the problem. Also, add a sample input with the expected output.

Comment: show us the code ,not only the assignment

Comment: updated the question and have code attached. but literally I have no idea how to work out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a set with the numbers that you need to delete and keep updating it while you read new lines. If the new line starts by one element in the set skip it and do not write it to the output file.

```py
to_delete = set()

with open('input_file', 'r') as input_file, open('output_file', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        first, _, raw_list, *_ = line.split('\t')
        if int(first) in to_delete:
            continue
        output_file.write(line)
        to_delete.update(ast.literal_eval(raw_list))
```

Comment: This is a great idea! but it shows an error message when running: too many values to unpack (expected 3). The error is on line :first, _, raw_list = line.split()

Comment: Try the new version (with `*_` as a last argument to unpack the remaining elements silently). With that unpacking structure you will only find probelms if you ever get something with 2 or less elements.